# Windows 8 поверх Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: windows-8, ubuntu

Как это реализовать? Чтобы разделы Убунту не стерлись.

Comment: Сложновато, вроде сначала проще win поставить а потом unix нежели наоборот.

Comment: зачем ставить бетку сырую или экстрима захотелось

Comment: :) ну да))

Comment: @victorubuntu, уже не сырая )))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если нужна полноценная ос (не на виртуалке), выдели пустой раздел под восьмёрку (GParted'ом например) и установи. потом загрузизсь с liveCD убунту и установи загрузчик в главную загрузочную запись (dev/sda)

Comment: Чем же виртуальная полноценнее невиртуальной?

Answer (score 1):

Нужно установить Win8 в виртуальной машине (например, qemu или virtualbox) )) тогда Ubuntu в безопасности.

Answer (score 1):

Если просто попробовать - ставьте в виртуалку, VirtualBox неплохо работает на убунте. Если хотите пользоваться на постоянной основе - на отдельный раздел. Если убунта уже стоит, win8 затрет звгрузчик, его надо будет восстановить. Делается это в принципе не очень сложно, если нужна информация как, обращайтесь.

Comment: где то почитал, что можно установить винду поверх линухи, а потом как то фиксит загрузочные сектора . Вот здесь то и стопорился.

Answer (score 1):

Почему бы не обратиться к первоисточнику? Там все отлично расписано [как поставить Windows, если на компе уже стоит Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot#Installing_Windows_After_Ubuntu)